# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

I created a `.so` file and put it in the location `/opt/lib` and added this path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` now after this when I try to compile my main program with the following command:

```
g++ -Wall -I/home/alwin/Development/Calculator/ main.cpp -lcalc -o calculator
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcalc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone help me with this. 
I created the shared library using the code blocks IDE

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add `-L/opt/lib` to your compiler parameters, this makes the compiler and linker search that path for `libcalc.so` in that folder.

Comment: Oh yeah I tried that too, still I got the same error :( see the following
alwin@alwin-laptop:~/Desktop/CPPTest$ g++ -Wall -I/home/alwin/Development/Calculator/ -L/opt/lib main.cpp -libcalc.so -o calculator
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libcalc.so
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Jay it's -lcalc, not -libcalc.so

Answer (score 3):

When you make the call to gcc it should say

```
g++ -Wall -I/home/alwin/Development/Calculator/ -L/opt/lib main.cpp -lcalc -o calculator

not -libcalc.so
```

I have a similar problem with auto-generated makes.

You can create a soft link from your compile directory to the library directory.
Then the library becomes "local".

```
cd /compile/directory

ln -s  /path/to/libcalc.so libcalc.so
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `-L/opt/lib` to tell `ld` to look there for shared objects.

Comment: Like I already mentioned in the previous comment, I did add -L/opt/lib is there anything else that I am missing :(

Answer (score 2):

@Alwin Doss 
You should provide the -L option before -l. You would have done the other way round probably. Try this :)

Answer (score 0):

export LDFLAGS=-L/path to lib/  this will solve the error